# failed to create symbolic link

Tags: 12.04

hey guys i need help with  im trying this in terminal

```
sudo bash -c 'for MSF in $(ls msf*); do ln -s /opt/metasploit-framework/$MSF /usr/local/bin/$MSF;done'
```

and i get this

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfbinscan': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfcli': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfconsole': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfd': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfelfscan': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfencode': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfmachscan': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfpayload': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfpescan': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfrop': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfrpc': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfrpcd': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfupdate': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/msfvenom': File exists
```

Comment: In which directory did you run it? /opt or /usr?

Comment: the directory was root   and now its worrking  ty  very muchhhhhh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you should [avoid parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and you certainly shouldn't do it with a `for` loop which will break it's arguments on whitespace (or whatever you have set `$IFS` to). A better way would be:

```
for i in /opt/metasploit-framework/*msf; do ln -s "$i" /usr/local/bin/; done
```

If you insist on using `ls`, a safer way would be:

```
ls -1 /opt/metasploit-framework/*msf | while IFS= read -r msf; do 
    ln -s /opt/metasploit-framework/"$i" /usr/local/bin/; done
```